# how do I transfer my iOS developer profile to another computer because of hardware failure?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, recovery, data-recovery, developer-program

Is it possible to transfer my iOS developer profile to another computer if my hardware failed but the hard disk is ok?

Comment: anyone tried this?